# Checking groups in KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I try to use Keycloak in spring boot app. And want to check if user belong to some group. If there any Opportunity in KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Beacuse now I can only checking roles like this:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Submits the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider to the AuthenticationManager
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    // Specifies the session authentication strategy
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests(a-> a
                .antMatchers("/customers*", "/users*")
                .hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please comment why answers are not satisfying? Otherwize, would you accept one?

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak spring adapters are [deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

You might have look at this tutorial I wrote: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication

It doesn't use KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (I use something more flexible and compatible with latest spring-security versions), but it demoes how to make use of random private claims for security rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write an `OncePerRequestFilter` where you extract the JWT, decode and find the information you need:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws
            ServletException, IOException {
    String authorizationHeaderValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authorizationHeaderValue != null && authorizationHeaderValue.toLowerCase().startsWith("bearer")) {
     
    String token = authorizationHeaderValue.substring(7, authorizationHeaderValue.length());
     
 // decode token, check the data you need
}

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```